How to query JSONB with multiple condition using supabase clientjs
I have this JSONB field in supabase postgresql with property like
[
  {
    "factor": 0.7,
    "house": "65d0b9ab4e89c77982c82ae2"
  },
  {
    "factor": 0.3,
    "house": "65d0b9de4e89c77982c82ae6"
  }
]

I want to query with this condition
house = 65d0b9ab4e89c77982c82ae2
factor >= 0.5

Is this possible via supabase clientjs?  I see .contains examples but could not find with multiple condition.
